# Port Mapping memory components not working

Tags: vhdl

I'm using Quartus II and i need to create a 256 x 4B (1KB) memory out of 8 components of 128x1B, but i'm a begginer in vhdl.

Here's the 128x1B component(this is not where the problem lies), created using MegaWizard Quartus II plugin:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

LIBRARY altera_mf;
USE altera_mf.all;

ENTITY RAM_128B_MegaWizard IS
PORT
(
    address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0);
    clock       : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
    data        : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
    wren        : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
);
END RAM_128B_MegaWizard;

ARCHITECTURE SYN OF ram_128b_megawizard IS

SIGNAL sub_wire0    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);

COMPONENT altsyncram
GENERIC (
    clock_enable_input_a        : STRING;
    clock_enable_output_a       : STRING;
    intended_device_family      : STRING;
    lpm_hint        : STRING;
    lpm_type        : STRING;
    numwords_a      : NATURAL;
    operation_mode      : STRING;
    outdata_aclr_a      : STRING;
    outdata_reg_a       : STRING;
    power_up_uninitialized      : STRING;
    widthad_a       : NATURAL;
    width_a     : NATURAL;
    width_byteena_a     : NATURAL
);
PORT (
        wren_a  : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        clock0  : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        address_a   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0);
        q_a : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        data_a  : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
);
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
q    <= sub_wire0(7 DOWNTO 0);

altsyncram_component : altsyncram
GENERIC MAP (
    clock_enable_input_a => "BYPASS",
    clock_enable_output_a => "BYPASS",
    intended_device_family => "Cyclone II",
    lpm_hint => "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD=NO",
    lpm_type => "altsyncram",
    numwords_a => 128,
    operation_mode => "SINGLE_PORT",
    outdata_aclr_a => "NONE",
    outdata_reg_a => "UNREGISTERED",
    power_up_uninitialized => "FALSE",
    widthad_a => 7,
    width_a => 8,
    width_byteena_a => 1
)
PORT MAP (
    wren_a => wren,
    clock0 => clock,
    address_a => address,
    data_a => data,
    q_a => sub_wire0
);

END SYN;
```

Now here's the problem. I'm trying to use port map to instantiate the memory components and i'm getting the following errors

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(50) near text "1.1";  expecting  "end", or "(", or an identifier, or a concurrent statement
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(51) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(53) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(55) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(57) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(60) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(62) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(64) near text ";";  expecting "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RAM_256x4B.vhd(66) near text ";";  expecting "<="
```

Here's the code. My address have to be of size 10 bits and i'm using a decoder and a mux through packages.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 

library work;
use work.RAM_128B_MegaWizard_package.all;
use work.dec1to2_package.all;
use work.mux2to1_package.all;

entity RAM_256x4B is 
generic( 
        depth : integer range 1 to 10 := 10; 
        width: integer range 1 to 32 := 32; 
        init_file : string := "init_file2.mif"); 
        -- .mif filename 

port(Clock : in std_logic; 
     WrEn: in std_logic; 
    -- write control signal 
     Address : in std_logic_vector(depth-1 downto 0); 
    -- read and write addresses 
     data : in std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0); 
    -- data to be written 
     DataOut : out std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0)); 
    -- memory read output 
end RAM_256x4B;

architecture behavior of RAM_256x4B is

signal dOut0: std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
signal dOut1: std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
signal En: std_logic_vector(0 to 1);

begin

    decoder: dec1to2 port map (Address(depth-3), WrEn, En);
        
    1.1: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(0), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(width-1 downto 24), dOut0(width-1 downto 24));
    1.2: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(0), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(23 downto 16), dOut0(23 downto 16));
    1.3: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(0), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(15 downto 8), dOut0(15 downto 8));       
    1.4: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(0), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(7 downto 0), dOut0(7 downto 0));
        
    2.1: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(1), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(width-1 downto 24), dOut1(width-1 downto 24));
    2.2: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(1), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(23 downto 16), dOut1(23 downto 16));
    2.3: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(1), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(15 downto 8), dOut1(15 downto 8));       
    2.4: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(1), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(7 downto 0), dOut1(7 downto 0));         

    mux: mux2to1 port map (dOut0, dOut1, Address(depth-3),DataOut);

end behavior;
```

I know it's incomplete, but whatever i do compilation gives me the same errors. Even if the part after begin and end architecture is just

```
1.1: RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
        (Clock, En(0), Address(depth-4 downto 0), data(width-1 downto 24), dOut0(width-1 downto 24));
```

the same will happen.

I understand port map can't be used inside a process, but a component with process(the 128x1B) also can't be port mapped? How can i combine these components to make what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're having a problem doing your port mapping by reference.  Here's the component you're instantiating:

```
address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0);
clock       : IN STD_LOGIC  := '1';
data        : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
wren        : IN STD_LOGIC ;
q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
```

So if you're doing by reference, you should have this instantiation:

```
 inst_1_1 : RAM_128B_MegaWizard port map
    (Address(depth-4 downto 0), Clock, data(width-1 downto 24), En(0), dOut0(width-1 downto 24));
```

Notice the placement of the signals.  This is why I prefer to do explicit port mapping, you'll make less mistakes.

Also I'm not sure what restrictions there are against your instantiation name, but 1.1 doesn't seem like a good name to me.  Try something that begins with a letter and only has underscores, not periods.

Answer (score 1):

A label is required to be an identifier.  These cause the Error (10500) VHDL... errors.

Either a basic identifier:

```
 basic_identifier ::=
     letter  { [ underline ] letter_or_digit }

 letter_or_digit ::=  letter | digit

 letter ::=  upper_case_letter | lower_case_letter
```

or an extended identifier:

```
 extended_identifier ::=
    \ graphic_character { graphic_character } \
```

In your case the labels (1.1, 1.2, etc.) need to start with a letter, sort of like Russel demonstrates in his answer incidentally and in addition to the incorrect positional association in the port interfaces where they are instantiated.

Fix both issues.